# Where to place device specific values in ios app?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, plist

In my app, I want some of the values to be device specific.

In android, I could use different resource files, and the correct one would be used according to the device I'm running on.

How can I achieve a similar behavior in ios?

Note:
I read about device [specific values in plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW1), but I can't seem to get the correct one when running on an ipad.

This is how I saw I can read values (and obviously it's not working since I simply read from a dictionary):

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"values" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
int number = [[dict objectForKey:@"colsInPage"] intValue];
```

**Edit:**

Here is an example for what I'm looking for:

I have a UICollectionView and I want to calc width for each item according to the number of columns I want to have. in an iphone, I want 4 cols, and in Ipad I want 6.

Comment: Is `dict` `nil` by chance? If it's not, can you post what you plist keys look like.

Comment: The page you link to is specific to the `Info.plist` file. How specific do your values need to be? Just iPhone vs. iPad or more granular?

Comment: See my edit for an example of what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can use [iOS Supports Device-Specific Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html) to open one file on iPhone, and a different file on the iPad, like people commonly do with images, without having to any device checks yourself.

You would name the iPhone version `colsInPage~iphone.plist`, and the iPad version `colsInPage~ipad.plist`. In the program, have it open `colsInPage.plist`, and iOS would pick the correct version automagically for you.

Answer (score 0):

The "specific values in plist" you are referring to only applies to `Info.plist`. The path you are building is to a plist filed named `values.plist`.

All apps require an `Info.plist`. It will be named something like `MyCoolApp-Info.plist". This file  specifies specific values for attributes related to the application such as orientations supported, status bar display, etc.

Add these raw values to your `Info.plist`

```
colsInPage          4
colsInPage~ipad     6
```

Now, provided you have put the keys in correctly, change your code as follows:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
int number = [[dict objectForKey:@"colsInPage"] intValue];
```

This will input 4 into number when you are on any device other than iPad (i.e. iPhone or iPod) and 6 when ran on an iPad.

Comment: Actually, it does do exactly what i think it will.

Comment: @ ColdLogic There is an implication that `[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]` strips non-matching keys and renames matching keys. Once one has a `NSDictionary` there is no context that it came from the App's bundle.

Comment: isn't adding values to Info.plist taking advantage of one of its abilities for something unrelated?

Comment: @rmaddy actually thats incorrect. In iOS 3.2 and later, apps can designate keys in the Info.plist file as being applicable only to specific types of devices.

Comment: @ColdLogic I just ran my own test and sure enough this does work. Very interesting. It seems there is some magic going on in the call to `[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]`. Good to know.

Comment: @ColdLogic Having said that though, I agree with "dors". I don't think it is a good idea to pollute Info.plist with app data.

Comment: @dors if you feel uncomfortable using the `Info.plist`, then you can use any of the `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` solutions that have been posted. It's your app :P

Comment: @rmaddy yea, I see where you're coming from, but in the end, all the data in info.plist is app data.

Comment: @ColdLogic My argument would be that Info.plist is a special file meant for configuring the app. It's not meant for general app data. But as you say, do what you want in your own app. :) Anyway, I learned something interesting today. Thanks.

Comment: There is certainly something going on with the `[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]` call but I am not getting the correct results in the iPad simulator, the iPhone simulator does work correctly, I have not tested on the device.

Comment: @Zaph how have you defined your keys/values?

Comment: <key>colsInPage</key>
<string>default</string>
<key>colsInPage~iphone</key>
<string>iphone</string>
<key>colsInPage~ipad</key>
<string>ipad</string>

Comment: @zaph and what values are you getting when running on each simulator?

Comment: I get "colsInPage = iPhone" for each for iPad Retina simulator. I am just NSLog'ing the dictionary. Code: `NSDictionary *dict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSLog(@"dict: %@", dict);`

Comment: @Zaph i copy pasted your key/values into my plist, ran on both iPhone and iPad simulator, and got the correct results.

Comment: NSLog(@"value = %@", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"colsInPage"]);

Comment: I will not arguing that nor can I explain my results. I am just puzzled. I can see that there was re-writing happening, just not correct for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your needs are simple - one set of values for all iPhone/iPod touch devices and another set of values for all iPads, then you can simply create two plist files with names such as "values-iphone.plist" and "values-ipad.plist".

Then you code can be:

```
NSString *path;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"values-ipad" ofType:@"plist"];
} else {
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"values-iphone" ofType:@"plist"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that.  We do something similar where we have an outer dictionary where the keys are the configuration, in your case that would be the device size or whatever you want the differentiating feature to be.  Those keys link to other dictionaries who's keys are the coorospond to the different values we want.  For example this is the meet an potatoes of what we do.

```
<dict>
    <key>iphone</key>
    <dict>
        <key>collumsPerPage</key>
        <string>5</string>
    </dict>
    <key>ipad</key>
        <key>collumsPerPage</key>
        <string>5</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

the keys iPhone and iPad are just examples, you'll have to find out how to relate those keys to something you can figure out programattically.  For example you could do

```
NSDictionary *plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:.......];

NSDictionary *valuesDict;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    valuesDict = plist[@"iphone"];
}

int number = [[valuesDict objectForKey:@"colsInPage"] intValue];
...
```